# ASP.Net Forms authentication issue

Tags: 2007, development, security

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I have deployed a collaboration portal template based SharePoint site collection. I am developing using ASP.Net web application using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net + SharePoint Server 2007 SDK. I am devloping a custom Forms authentication component (a DLL) and wants to register it to be used in SharePoint sites.

I heard for SharePoint Server 2007, custom Forms authentication can only be used for publishing portal and can not be used for collaboration portal. Is that true?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form Based Authentication (FBA) works fine across different templates (publishing and collaboration is just that, a template).

You will run into issues though using FBA with regards to indexing your solution, so you need to extend your web application with a zone using NTFS to allow the crawler to crawl your site.

Also client integration wont work using FBA (or Web Single-Sign On). Client integration is a feature that allows you to start client applications from your document items context menus, and sharepoint designer authoring. Links to open documents in client applications will be removed and documents will open in browser instead of client when client integrations is disabled.

Comment: Thanks. I do not need to configure client integration. And no need to crawl the site. Any special steps to configure custom Forms authentication using collaboration portal v.s. using publishing portal?

Comment: I am following steps here, and after configuring Forms authentication, then I begin to browse the site default front page, there is 404 error. Any ideas?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975135.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975136.aspx